# AngularJS - Filter Out Raw Data In ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm attempting to hide or filter out the raw data from a `ng-repeated` table. Basically, I have a table and a small navigation menu, when I click on a nav item it will pull the data from an array and the table will render that data.

The problem here is that for a second or two, I see the raw data {{data.name}}. Is there any way to filter it out until ng-repeat has finished populating?

[Picture of what I'm speaking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22bnE.png)

I have also attempted to use `ng-cloak`, on the modal itself as well as the table tags, but I can't seem to get `ng-cloak` working, even with the proper css implmented.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="modal is-active" ng-show="navCtrl.isModalActive('chooseItem')" ng-controller="RpgDataController as rpgData">
        <div class="modal-background" ng-click="navCtrl.closeModal('chooseItem')"></div>
        <div class="modal-card">
            <header class="modal-card-head">
                <p class="modal-card-title">Choose An Item</p>
                <button class="delete" ng-click="navCtrl.closeModal('chooseItem')"></button>
            </header>

            <!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
            <!--                                 Navigation Contents                                            -->
            <!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
            <nav class="nav has-shadow">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="nav-left">
                        <a class="nav-item is-tab" ng-click="navCtrl.setItemData('items')"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i> &nbsp; Items</a>
                        <a class="nav-item is-tab" ng-click="navCtrl.setItemData('weapons')"><i class="fa  fa-wrench-o"></i> &nbsp; Weapons</a>
                        <a class="nav-item is-tab" ng-click="navCtrl.setItemData('armors')"><i class="fa fa-wrench" ></i> &nbsp; Armors</a>
                        <a class="nav-item is-tab" ng-click="navCtrl.setItemData('armors')"><i class="fa fa-wrench" ></i> &nbsp; Gold</a>
                        <a class="nav-item is-tab" ng-click="navCtrl.setItemData('armors')"><i class="fa fa-wrench" ></i> &nbsp; Exp</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <section class="modal-card-body">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody ng-repeat="data in rpgData.activeData.data">
                            <th ng-cloak>{{data.name}}</th>
                            <th  ng-cloak>{{data.id}}</th>
                            <th  ng-cloak>{{data.description}}</th>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </section>
            <footer class="modal-card-foot">
                <a class="button is-primary" ng-click="navCtrl.saveDataType('config')">Save changes</a>
                <a class="button" ng-click="navCtrl.closeModal('chooseItem')">Cancel</a>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have added the proper CSS? ```[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}```

Comment: @roger Yup, I have this at the top of my CSS file. [link]([Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/fuhNylZ.png)) I have also tried adding it directly to the HTML head section, still no luck.